# IF statement to run even if the requirement isn't met anymore

Tags: arduino-nano, analogread, analogwrite

I have built a flasher for the headlamps on my race car. Whilst it works when I hold the switch down, if I release the switch and the circuit is closed my IF statements requirements are no longer met and it stops flashing.

Is there a way to have it continue to run the IF statement (but only once) even after I've let go of the switch and the requirement is no longer met?

Thanks in advance.

CODE:

```
#define trig A3

const int flash = 3; //D3
const float mVc = 4.67; //reference voltage
float counts = 0;
float mV = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(flash, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  counts = analogRead(trig);
  //counts = 255;
  Serial.println(String(counts));

  mV = (counts*mVc) / 1000;
  Serial.println("Input Voltage: " + String(mV) + "v");

  //delay(1000);
  
// voltage will need to be changed to matched output voltage when on car
  if (counts > 10) {
    analogWrite(flash, 100);
    delay(300);
    analogWrite(flash, 0);
    delay(80);
    analogWrite(flash, 100);
    delay(300);
    analogWrite(flash, 0);
    delay(80);
    analogWrite(flash, 100);
    delay(300);
    analogWrite(flash, 0);
    delay(80);
    analogWrite(flash, 100);
    delay(300);
    analogWrite(flash, 0);
    delay(80);
    analogWrite(flash, 100);
    delay(300);
    analogWrite(flash, 0);
    delay(1000);       
  }
}
```

---

EDIT:

TL;DR Don't use voltage dividers to power the Nano.

When using a voltage divider to power the Nano (I know, I know) the below solution didn't fix the issue. I thought it may be due to the voltage dropping when the Nano supplies the 5vo to the mosfet but I'm not sure why holding the switch would stop that from happening. Regardless I swapped to a linear voltage regulator and then it started to flash, *"Hurrah!"* -- almost.

With the regulator in it was running the code constantly. I decided to print the runcount and I got a number over 35,000, meaning it would run the flash 5 times for >35,000 times. Although curious as to what would happen when it reached zero, I decided to go back to my original code and...now it works.

So I guess the lesson is: Even if you can calculate the drop off, don't run your Nano on a voltage divider.

---

**I have checked the answer below as the solution, although it didn't fix my issue there is no reason it shouldn't have worked and it may be useful to someone else.**

Comment: why are you using analog I/O?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define an `int runcount = 0` variable at the top. Then change your loop logic to something like

```
if (counts > 10) {
  runcount = 2;
}

if (runcount-- > 0) {
  //flashy flashy 
}
```

The effect is, that while button is pressed and `counts > 10`, runcount is set to two. Every time we check the runcount, it is decreased by 1. While the button is pressed, runcount is resat to 2. If you let go of the button, runcount will be 1 at the start of the if condition check. It will be compared to 0, condition will be true, and it will then be decreased to 0 and the if section will be executed one last time. Using another number than 2 will change the number of extra runs.

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a go tomorrow and then all that is left is the "easy" bit of fitting it to the car. :)